# method for comparing strings in php

Tags: php

I want to compare two strings and return a level of comparison.

String 1 is the input and can come in a range of formats from clients. For example:

```
string 1 - "GCSE English Lang Year 10" or
string 1 - "Year 10 Eng Lang GCSE" etc
```

String 2 is the string I want to compare it with. For example:

```
string 2 - "English Language"
```

I realise I can use `preg_match` to look for an exact pattern:

```
$subject = $inputString;
$pattern= "/Eng/";
if (preg_match($pattern, $inputString))
{
echo "match";
}
```

But is there a method that will return an factor of match, rather than simply yes or no? I realise there may be a more complex coding answer using the `preg_match` type method but I wonder if there something already around I have not found.

Comment: *an factor of match,* Please describe this a bit more what the expected results would be here

Comment: Well I am thinking anything like a score from 1 to 100 perhaps.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php might be another good one, even calcs % similar if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`levenshtein()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php) function:

> The Levenshtein distance is defined as the minimal number of characters you have to replace, insert or delete to transform str1 into str2. The complexity of the algorithm is O(m*n), where n and m are the length of str1 and str2 (rather good when compared to similar_text(), which is O(max(n,m)**3), but still expensive).

For example the Levenshtein distance for "English Language" and "GCSE English Lang Year 10" is 12.

```
$lev = levenshtein('GCSE English Lang Year 10', 'English Language');
echo $lev; // 12
```

Comment: That looks like something that could work. Thanks - I will have a look at that. Either way, a good function to know about - cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You have most of what you need. You need to capture the match you found and then you can use levenshtein to see how different it is from the the complete word.

```
$subject = $inputString;
$pattern= "/Eng[a-zA-Z]+/"; // I made it clear that I want all letters in the word. 
$matches = array(); // This is an array of all the words that match.
if (preg_match($pattern, $inputString, $matches))
{
    $match = $matches[0]; // Check first match - assume only one matched.
    $diff = levenshtein(strtolower($match), 'english');
    print "Found $match which is $diff edits from English.\n";
}
```

Now, the max $diff will be: `max(strlen($match), strlen('english'));`. If you set $max to the maximum difference, the similarity from 0 to 100 would be `100*($max-$diff)/$max;` - but I advise you don't do that. It is a poor metric. Stick with $diff and look for the lowest $diff.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like:

```
$string1 = "GCSE English Lang Year 10";
$string2 = "Year 10 Eng Lang GCSE";

$i = array_intersect(
    str_word_count(strtolower($string1), 2),
    str_word_count(strtolower($string2), 2)
);
$similarityPercentage = count($i) / max(count($array1), count($array2)) * 100;
```

which calculates the percentage of identical words in the two strings, though it doesn't allow for the abbreviation of `English` to `Eng`