# how to preg match a string with a levenshtein distance in PHP

Tags: php, preg-match, levenshtein-distance

How can I preg match a string, but tolerate a variable levensthein distance in the pattern?

```
$string = 'i eat apples and oranges all day long';
$find = 'and orangis';
$distance = 1;
$matches = pregMatch_withLevensthein($find, $distance, $string);
```

This would return 'and oranges';

Comment: This question was already answered here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29781719/method-for-comparing-strings-in-php

Comment: Mine is different, because I want to find one or two words in a book, and allow the words to be slightly misspelled. That question is straight up levenshtein distance. If I used the levenshtein distance on my example, it wouldn't return "and oranges". I need to check if the string contains "and orangis" or a string thats the same with 1 character wrong. As the string gets bigger I would increase the levenshtein distance.

Comment: You'd need to convert your $find variable into a similar regex, then with all the matches you'd use the levensthein comparison. If it is just text that should be fairly easy to do. What do you want the function to return, a single match or all the matches?

Comment: Chappell, finding the similar pattern is where I'm lost. It seems the only way to actually do this is to go from one character to the next, and then use levensthtein on the next X characters until it finds a match of 0 or 1 distance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By converting the search string into a regexp, we can match the pattern. Then we search using that regexp and do a comparison with levenshtein. If it matches the bounds we can return the values.

```
$string = 'i eat apples and oranges all day long';
$find = 'and orangis';
$distance = 1;
$matches = preg_match_levensthein($find, $distance, $string);
var_dump($matches);

function preg_match_levensthein($find, $distance, $string)
{
    $found = array();

    // Covert find into regex
    $parts = explode(' ', $find);
    $regexes = array();
    foreach ($parts as $part) {
        $regexes[] = '[a-z0-9]{' . strlen($part) . '}';
    }
    $regexp = '#' . implode('\s', $regexes) . '#i';

    // Find all matches
    preg_match_all($regexp, $string, $matches);

    foreach ($matches as $match) {
        // Check levenshtein distance and add to the found if within bounds
        if (levenshtein($match[0], $find) <= $distance) {
            $found[] = $match[0];
        }
    }

    // return found
    return $found;
}
```

Comment: This does actually answer the question, so I'm accepting it. Thanks Chappell. Unfortunately, it won't work for something like  "andoranges" :(

Comment: It will if you change the implode to something like `(\s?)` which would find zero or one space character.